# SQLDataLReader and CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

wondering if anyone could answer my question:

A few days ago, I was writing a few SQLDataReaders for my webapp and I came across an issue I have never had before, also, the readers just before this one were working fine.

IE:

Working SQLDataReader:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
   Constants.Department = reader[1].ToString();
   Constants.Channelid = reader[2].ToString();
}
```

Then I created another, almost exactly like that one, IE:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

while (reader.Read())
{
    Label9.Text = reader.GetString(0);
    Label20.Text = reader.GetString(1);
    Label21.Text = reader.GetString(2);
    Label22.Text = reader.GetString(3);
}
```

And this one would not work until I added "CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess".. So, long story short, what exactly does "CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess" do?? I have been reading and reading and cant find anything that explains this to me.

Comment: you threw me off with IE.  I'd try to use i.e. instead

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx) seems reasonably clear to me - what don't you understand about it?

Comment: @JonSkeet: If the OP's code is really like his post, though, there does not seem to be a good reason why SequentialAccess would be required in this case.

Comment: Sorry - let me elaborate, I may have been quite vague in my question I guess. the reader kept giving me an error that it could only find one column. when I knew there was meant to be four (stored proc was the datasource for this reader)

It would set label9.Text but then for the others it would error saying "Object out of array", and it did this until I added CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess... Hope this clears it up a bit?

Comment: I assume that you're not using the `using`-statement or closing the command/connection manually. Then you are vulnerable to a timeout.  Is the connection static?

Comment: What is the SQL statement and what is the exact error?

Comment: SQL Query was " SELECT Status, f_approved, m_approved, t_approved FROM Submissions WHERE UserName = @Username "... And the exact error was "Index was outside the bounds of the array" [0] worked, and [1][2][3] would not work until I added that CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess

Answer (score -1):

Simply, the CommandBehavior executes the reader and the SequentialAccess speeds up through large result sets. I don't exactly know what's wrong, but SequentialAccess loads a single column at one time so, it assures the sequence of column loading.

Comment: So why does it work with `SequentialAccess` if he just selects a few text-fields?

Comment: I don't think this explains what he wants to know.